# count distinct concat in BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I have tried PostgreSQL:count distinct (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) 
           in BigQuery :Count distinct concat(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

My scenario is I need to get same result as PostgreSQL in BigQuery

Though this scenario works on 3 columns ,I am not getting same value as PostgreSQL for 5 columns.

sample query:

```
 select col1,
count(distinct concat((col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
from table A
group by col1
```

when I remove distinct and concat, simple count(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) gives exact value as populated in PostgreSQL. But i need to have distinct of these columns. Is there any way to achieve this? and does bigquery concat works differently?

Comment: Please show example input and output.

Comment: Occam's razor:  the data is different. Do you know the answer in advance? If not did you prove the data in the separate databases is actually the same?

Answer (score 1):

Below few options for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT TO_JSON_STRING((col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)))
FROM A
GROUP BY col1
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT FORMAT('%T', [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]))
FROM A
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative suitable for the many databases that don't support that form of `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Origin, Dest, Reporting_Airline 
  FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.ontime_201908` 
  WHERE FlightDate_year = "2018-01-01" 
)
```

My guess on why `CONCAT` didn't work in your sample: Do you have any null columns?